# MYSQL: condition _IN_ doesn't work correct

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

So I have column 'CLM' in the table where one record has follow value: '4,6,1'.

I do follow select:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 6 IN (CLM)
got nothing then.

I do follow select:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 4 IN (CLM)
got record described behind.

Cannot understand why first query works wrong?

Comment: CLM gives you the string '4,6,1'. It does not give you a list (which is defined using literal `,`s in the query). Normalise your database and look up individual numbers in a linked table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function even though it would be better you normalize your table as already suggested.